# How to filter object array on condition in nested array (to-many relationship) in iOS Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, relationship

I am attempting to filter an array of objects on a matching condition within a nested to-many relationship and unsure how to write the filter.

To illustrate this, consider I have modeled a system that manages people applying to college and have modeled the following entities and relationships:

- Person entity that has a to-many relationship with a School entity
- School entity that has a to-one relationship with a SchoolType entity (in addition to the inverse to-many relationship with the Person entity)
- SchoolType entity that has to-one relationship with a
  FinancialAwardType entity (in addition to the inverse to-many relationship with School entity)
- FinancialAwardType entity

The FinancialAwardType entity simply captures different types of financial awards such as grant, merit scholarship, or loan, for example.

For the purposes of this example, the requirement is that financial awards are specific to school types, hence modeling the relationship between the SchoolType and FinancialAwardType entities as such.

What I want to be able to do is create a filter that will give me the subset of Person entities that have applied to schools that offer a specific type of financial award, and am having difficulty determining how to write such a filter given the nested 'to many' relationships.

I can potentially do this in multiple steps, such as:

1. filtering the list of SchoolTypes to give me just SchoolTypes that offer merit awards....
2. then, filter Schools to give me only those Schools that are of one of the filtered SchoolTypes....
3. then, filter Persons to give me only those Persons that have applied to
   those filtered Schools...

This seems somewhat inefficient and wondering if there's a more elegant solution for performing the filter I am seeking.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  If needed, I can show the code or attempted code segments that I have tried for the above steps.

In response to some of the comments and suggestions...my hope was to use filter() to return the collection of Persons...something like this:

```
    let personsReceivingGrants = persons.schoolsApplied.filter() {

        $0.schoolType?.awardType?.name == "Grant Award"
    }
```

The problem is that the Person->School to-many relationship gets defined as an NSSet of Any, and Any has no type schoolType... Is it possible to be more specific in terms of telling the compiler what type of object is in the NSSet so that I can use the filter() mechanism?  Or is there another more appropriate approach to achieve this filtering?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help.

Comment: It depends on what data base you are using, what performance you are looking for, it prefetch query or in-memory array filtering etc...

Comment: I am using coredata and swift and was attempting to build a filter on the collection as follows, but unable to do that bc the relationship gets defined as an NSSet of Any type object and it needs to be dealing with the specific School entity/object type        let personsReceivingGrants = persons.schoolsApplied.filter() {

            $0.schoolType?.awardType?.name == "Grant Award"
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So once I edited my question in response to the suggestions here, and talked it out more, I realized the issue was simply a matter of being more specific with the type in the NSSet.  So I changed the code to the following and that now works. I wanted to post that solution here in case others run into the same challenge:

```
    let personsReceivingGrants = (persons.schoolsApplied as Set<School>).filter() {

        $0.schoolType?.awardType?.name == "Grant Award"
    }
```